# Empty State doesn't get displayed

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component which gets an array of items passed down from its parent component. Everything gets correctly displayed and deleting items works as well. But once the last item in the table was deleted, the empty state does not show. Only once I reload the page the empty state gets shown.

I'm new to react and probably just don't fully understand the state/props management yet.

Can someone please explain? Thanks in advance.

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import { Message } from "semantic-ui-react";
import BasarService from "../../../../services/BasarService";
import BasarTable from "./components/BasarTable/BasarTable";

class Basars extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      basars: []
    };

    this.basarService = new BasarService();
    this.deleteBasar = this.deleteBasar.bind(this);
  }

  deleteBasar(id) {
    this.basarService.delete(id, response => {
      var filteredBasars = this.state.basars.filter(basar => basar.id !== id);
      this.setState({
        basars: filteredBasars
      });

      console.log("Success:", response);
    });
  }

  getBasars() {
    this.basarService.getAll(data => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        basars: data
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBasars();
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, basars } = this.state;

    const ErrorMessage = () => (
      <Message negative>
        <Message.Header>Basars could not be loaded!</Message.Header>
        <p>{error.message}</p>
      </Message>
    );

    if (error) {
      return ErrorMessage();
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <BasarTable basars={basars} deleteBasar={this.deleteBasar} />
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Basars;
```

Child:

```
import React from "react";
import { Table, Button, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { formatDate } from "../../../../../../util/timeFormat";

class BasarTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick(basarId) {
    this.props.deleteBasar(basarId);
  }

  render() {
    const { basars } = this.props;

    const BasarRows = basars => (
      basars.map(basar => (
        <Table.Row key={basar.id}>
          <Table.Cell>{basar.id}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{basar.type}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{formatDate(basar.startdate)}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{formatDate(basar.enddate)}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Button icon color="red" onClick={() => this.handleClick(basar.id)}>
              <Icon name="trash" />
            </Button>
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      ))
    );

    const EmptyState = (
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell colSpan="5" textAlign="center">
          <Icon name="frown" />No basars found!
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    );


    return (
      <Table celled>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>StartDate</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>EndDate</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {basars ? BasarRows(basars) : EmptyState}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default BasarTable;
```

Comment: explain `deleteBasar` to us!

Comment: How are you deleting? What's in state once the last item is deleted? There's a difference between an empty array and nothing--you're checking for nothing (`null`/`undefined`/falsey), not an empty array.

Comment: @asiniy I added the parent context as well, sorry about that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I did try this ` {(basars.length > 0) ? BasarRows(basars) : EmptyState}` which works, but then once there are no basars left I of course get a **Cannot read property 'length' of null**. I just can't figure out how to do it properly and would really like to know the "best" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Empty array is still a truthy so please change the condition in your child component to `basars.length > 0 ? BasarRows(basars) : EmptyState`

Comment: Yeah, I did try this and it works, but then once there are no basars left I of course get a **"Cannot read property 'length' of null"**. I just can't figure out how to do it properly and would really like to know the "best practice" way to build these parent/child components.

Comment: Have you tried console logging `filteredBasars` just before `setState` if so can you tell what's logging each time including when you delete everything

Comment: Sorry, I have to clarify that the error only appears if there is no basar left anymore AND I then do a reload. The empty state does show this way.

Comment: Can you try console logging and let me know the output after each delete till the error appears.

Comment: I start with 2 items. After first delete it logs an array with length 1. After second delete it logs an array with length 0. Then the empty state appears. If I reload it throws an error, because `basars` is null and I'm calling `.length` on null.

Comment: I'm thinking there is a totally different, much cleaner way to do this, but I'm not sure how. Is the way I do it with state in parent and props in child good?

Comment: By reload what do you mean? Once all the items are deleted then the empty state appears right so why reload?

Answer (score 0):

You need remember filter function always return new array ( empty array as well )